# Calculate an equation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a calculator with javascript. My problem is I don't know how to turn the equation into the result. Below is my code.

```
function equal(){
    var x=eval(result.innerHTML);
    result.innerHTML=x;
}
```

for example if the equation is 2*3+5, how do I return the result 11 into the html below?

```
<div class="monitor" id="result">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a button and call `equal` function with `onclick` event.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjeu8sxf/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const result = document.querySelector('#result')

document.querySelector('#equation').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  try {
    result.innerHTML = eval(e.target.value)
  } catch {
    result.innerHTML = 'Invalid'
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="equation" type="text" />
<div id="result"></div>
```